# Anyone has any good link to documents for Compaction & Downsampling?

Tags: prometheus, downsampling

I have been trying to get hold of compaction & Downsampling implemented in Prometheus (And Thanos).

I somewhat understood the storage based on LSM, but not finding any good documents on compactions(levelled based) that is used. Any pointers ?